# Why is "elle" needed in "Pourquoi la nature est-elle polluée ?"?

Tags: grammaire

I read the following sentence:

> Pourquoi la nature est-elle polluée ?

But I think the subject here is *la nature* and the verb is *est*, with *polluée* is an adjective.

So the following sentence should be fine:

> Pourquoi est la nature polluée ?

But then why is it transformed into *est-elle* and what is the difference between the two sentences?

Comment: @aCOSwt Thanks for pointing it out. Is it considered a duplicate here if the question and answers are written in different languages? Sorry, I just started to learn French this week, and don't understand what is written there yet.

Comment: Try the one above, which I wrote in English. It's hard to find existing answers on language SEs, since the grammar questions are almost always addressed through random specific sentences people find, but this one is a surprisingly exact match :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak Yes and I was actually trying to close the question, only found that it had just got closed 20 seconds ago. The linked one is the great answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't construct a "why" sentence in French exactly like you do in English.

It's actually pretty similar if you look at it the right way:

> *Is nature polluted?* = La nature est-elle polluée ?
>
> *Why [is nature polluted]?* = Pourquoi [la nature est-elle polluée] ?

It works the same way with the other ways to ask a question in French:

> Est-ce que la nature est polluée ?  → Pourquoi [est-ce que la nature est polluée] ?
>
> La nature est polluée ?  → Pourquoi [la nature est polluée] ?

So a "why" question in French is just a normally constructed question with a "*pourquoi*" in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if the subject is NOT a pronoun, you must add the pronoun of the subject as well as the subject itself. In this case, since the `la nature` is the subject but not is a pronoun, you must add `elle`, a pronoun for the third-person singular (female).

So for example, if the subject is a pronoun, you can just invert the subject and verb:

> Vous parlez italien.
>
> Parlez-vous italien?

But in the following case, you need to add a pronoun:

> La petite fille veut un vélo.
>
> La petite fille veut-**elle** un vélo?

---

Source: https://www.dummies.com/languages/french/how-to-form-a-question-in-french-using-inversion/

Comment: Note that *la petite fille veut un vélo ?* is actually common in spoken French. The interrogative intonation is enough to make clear it is a question.