# 'Les hommes sont-ils obsolètes ?' -- What is this type of question structure?

Tags: grammaire, questions

I have come across many questions which appear to have both the noun and a pronoun that act as the subject. For example, I just ran into this particular question:

**'Les hommes sont-ils obsolètes ?'**

Here, I believe that **Les hommes** and **ils** are the same subject. I can rewrite the question as 'Les hommes sont obsolètes ?' without changing the meaning of the question.

Can someone help me out here by telling me why is 'ils' also part of the question? Is this a particular way of writing questions in French. I would be happy if someone helps me out by clarifying this for me or point me out to any reading sources on this particular topic.

Comment: Check the answers under this question and if you have more questions don't hesitate to put them to the FSE: https://french.stackexchange.com/q/39879/17649

Comment: Actually, these questions are probably closer duplicates: https://french.stackexchange.com/q/24563/4082, https://french.stackexchange.com/q/32700/4082 (I already submitted my close vote, so I can't formally suggest a new duplicate.)

Comment: Thank you everyone. Your suggested questions answer my doubts.